# Apache Spark custom log4j configuration for application

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to customize the Log4J configuration for my application in a standalone Spark cluster. I have a log4j.xml file which is inside my application JAR. What is the correct way to get Spark to use that configuration instead of its own Log4J configuration?

I tried using the --conf options to set the following, but no luck.

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -> -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml
```

I am using Spark 1.4.1 and there's no log4j.properties file in my /conf.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using SBT as package manager/builder:

There is a `log4j.properties.template` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf`

- copy it in your SBT project's `src/main/resource`
- remove the `.template` suffix
- edit it to fit your needs
- SBT run/package/* will include this in JAR and Spark references it.

Works for me, and will probably include similar steps for other package managers, e.g. maven.

Comment: I am using Gradle to build  the project. I placed a copy of the template file in my src/main/resources and removed the .template suffix and deployed. But still no luck. I inspected the final JAR and I see the log4j.properties file in it. When I check the logs from the Spark UI for application, I see the text "Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties" in it still.

Comment: Excuse me for misunderstanding your question, above will only work for self-contained spark app. If you want to change your cluster's logging behavior, duplicate `log4j.properties.template` to the same dir, remove the `.template` and edit new file. This should be done for every instance in cluster. There is also `sc.setLogLevel("LEVEL")`, but I can't understand how it behaves, yet.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to see whether there's a way to do it without touching the cluster configuration. If all else fails, I'd go down that path.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `driver-java-options`.  For example:

```
spark-submit --class my.class --master spark://myhost:7077 --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/apps/conf/my.log4j.properties" my.jar
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I am trying to do this on a cluster. We are using spark on YARN. I tried all the above this adding to the resources file , passing --driver-java-options in the submit command as shown above But nothing works for me. It still picks the default Jar

Comment: When running in cluster mode, you have to add the file to classpath by using: `--files file:///opt/apps/conf/my.log4j.properties`

Comment: This only works on driver level, in distributed mode you must deploy the log4j either on hadoop first, so path is visible for each executor modes, or use --files option for submit, so the file is distributed across all nodes.